# How to complete the triangle inequality proof?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am writing down the proof of the triangle inequality

$$|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$$

The steps are as followed:

By definition of absolute value, for all $x,y$:

1. $x\leq |x| \iff -|x|\leq x \leq |x|$
2. $y\leq |y| \iff -|y|\leq y \leq |y|$

Adding up 1 and 2 we get:

$$-|x|-|y|\leq x+y \leq |x|+|y|$$

$$-(|x|+|y|)\leq x+y \leq |x|+|y|$$

Which is by definition is:

$$x+y\leq (|x|+|y|)$$

It maybe a subtle point, but how do we get to

$$|x+y|\leq (|x|+|y|)$$?

Comment: You have to set various parameters for x and y, so one case is $x<0,y>0$ and so on.

Comment: By definition $$-|x|-|y|\leq x+y \leq |x|+|y|\iff |x+y|\le |x|+|y|$$ so you already proved it. Observe that the LHS is the definition of the RHS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inequalities resulted by summing up 1 and 2 prove exactly the triangle inequality. Namely: $$|u|\le a\iff -a\le u\le a.$$ Applying it to $u=x+y$ and $a=|x|+|y|$, i.e. to $$-(|x|+|y|)\le x+y\le |x|+|y|,$$ we get a desired inequality.

Answer (score 1):

$$\\ \\ \begin{cases} \begin{cases} x\le \left| x \right|  \\ y\le \left| y \right|  \end{cases}\Rightarrow x+y\le \left| x \right| +\left| y \right|  \\ \begin{cases} -x\le \left| x \right|  \\ -y\le \left| y \right|  \end{cases}\Rightarrow -x-y\le \left| x \right| +\left| y \right| \Rightarrow -\left( x+y \right) \le \left| x \right| +\left| y \right|  \end{cases}\Rightarrow \left| x+y \right| \le \left| x \right| +\left| y \right| $$

Answer (score 0):

Check the step where you say "Which by definition is" carefully. Recall that the inequality $|x|\le a$ is equivalent to $-a\le x\le a$. Your proof should be complete once you fix that step.